# Where condition on some of the records in results

Tags: sql-server

How can I filter some of the results in the result set?
For example, my dataset looks like the following:

[image]

I want to get all the records, but for Name = 'Peter', I don't want ' - ' appear in final result. ('Apple -' for Steven is ok and 'Apple' for Peter is ok as well)

Besides using the cursor, what it the best way (or most efficient way to do it?)

For example, if my condition is select all user, but when Name is Peter and product contains '-', then don't select it. But when user Name is Peter and product doesn't contain '-', then select it as result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use a `CASE` statement to do that

```
SELECT Name, 
       Product = CASE WHEN Name = 'Peter' THEN REPLACE(Product, '-', '') ELSE Product END
```

EDIT :

to exclude `Peter` and Product with `-` from the result, use `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE NOT (Name = 'Peter' and Product like '%-%')
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I would like to just get the result but not replace the record. For example if my condition is select all user, but when user name is Peter, and product contains '-', then don't select it. But when user name is Peter and product doesn't contain '-', then select it as result

Comment: Nice! Thank you Squirrel

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is a list of all results where the name is peter and there is not a '-' in the product.  The following SQL would deliver that:

```
SELECT *
FROM   <table>
WHERE  Name = 'Peter'
   AND NOT Product LIKE '%-%'
```

Comment: I think OP wanted all records not only `Peter`.